# Getting a boolean value for the difference between two images

Tags: c++-cli, emgucv

I'm trying to get the difference between a thresholded image and the original image, both of which are grayscale. My logic is that if that there is no difference between the the thresholded image and the original image, then that means that there was nothing to threshold.

So I want to find the difference between the images, and if there is no difference, then I will output a "0" to the user interface I made with my camera, and if there is a difference, then I will output a "1".

I tried using the AbsDiff method and I tried using the MatchTemplate method, but neither of those worked, and I'm out of ideas.

I've searched around the internet and haven't found anything to be of much help. Has anyone does something like this before? Does anyone have any pointers as to what I should do?

Comment: I assume you're looking for differences in RGB values? Some newlines would help your post.

Comment: they're grayscale images, i guess i should've specified that @JDong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with emgu CV, but to do this type of comparison, I'd iterate over each pixel in the image, and return 'not equal' if any are different between the two images.

(Edit: Logically, this is iterating over each pixel in the image and comparing. For efficiency though, I'd probably get the two image buffers (i.e., of size Width * Height * BytesPerPixel), and use `memcmp` on them. It's reasonable to assume that `memcmp` is about as optimized a solution as you're going to get for comparing two large buffers, and you want to avoid a `GetPixel` or similar accessor.)

Also, I wouldn't characterize this as getting a 'numerical value for the difference'. When you phrase it like that, I think of a range of numeric values: Zero means they're equal, small numbers means they're slightly different, large numbers means they're very different. If all you're looking for is a 0 or 1, then that's a Boolean, not a numerical value. Getting a Boolean value of 'equal'/'not equal' is much easier than attempting to quantify how much two images are different.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing things pixel by pixel, doesn't that slow down the framerate significantly?

Comment: It might, but you haven't told us much about your project, so it's hard to say anything for sure. No matter what method you choose, *something* is going to have to iterate over every single pixel in both the source and destination image. If you're on a low-powered CPU, then using the CPU for this, as I've outlined, might not be the best solution if you have some dedicated video hardware you can offload this to. That said, I'd implement this solution first and get it working: You may find that it's plenty fast, and you don't need to go further.

Comment: I'm trying to detect flashing LED's that are flashing a morse code and then decode that morse code and output it to the user interface, so that anyone can use it without having to know morse. The frame rate is an issue because the slower the framerate, then the slower the message will have to be relayed. Thank you very much for your help, I'll do as you suggested and try going over it pixel by pixel and see how that goes.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to detect the saturation in your imager that happens when the LED is lit. One thing you can do is to cut down on the image size, both overall and in the portion you're looking at. A bright LED will saturate a 160x120 pixel just as well as it does a 1920x1080 pixel, so you can turn down the resolution of your capture. Also, if you know where the LED is within the image, you only need to inspect that portion of the image, not the whole thing.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, and I have a mask that makes the LED show up as red, and it's a stationary feed, so I guess it would make more sense to look in the area that was defined by the mask, rather than the entire frame. If there's a red pixel in the area that would be masked, then the LED is on, and if there aren't any red pixels in that area, then the LED is off.

Answer (score 1):

My emguCV knowledge isn't extensive but have you tried using the emguCV's [`Cmp`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/85e3d711-f6cf-7be5-f4e1-4756ba624e22.htm) method to create a difference mask and then [`CountNonzero`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/78abf622-70c1-9415-f7c5-27469fddf4a4.htm) to find out if there is in fact a difference.